# name and rules of a numerical card game

Tags: identify-this-game, probability

I am looking for some information about a pokerlike game where 2 cards with numbers from 1 to 60 are dealt to each player and and bets are related to number representing an average number from of all not dealt cards. I only heard once what this game is about, I don't know the name of this game. I am trying to get some info about it.

**Do you know what are the name and rules of this game?**

Comment: What is the time period and geographic location you heard about or played this game? I think a 60 card numbered deck is quite unusual, but the Milton Bradley game [Rack-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack-O) uses them. Could it be this was simply a custom game someone made up that uses those cards?